# Select all the columns from a table corresponding to the max and min value of a particular column

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table which contains data in the below format :

```
Mand_ID Type            Sub_Type D_Freq Limit_Type      mon_freq   Val  Units
======= =======         ======== ====== ===========     =========  ==== ======= 
IAC901  TRACKING_ERROR  EX_ANTE  NA     LESS_THAN       MONTHLY    200  BASIS_POINTS
IAC901  TRACKING_ERROR  EX_ANTE  NA     GREATER_THAN    MONTHLY    150  BASIS_POINTS
IAC901  TRACKING_ERROR  EX_ANTE  NA     LESS_THAN       MONTHLY    450  BASIS_POINTS
IAC901  TRACKING_ERROR  EX_ANTE  NA     GREATER_THAN_EQ MONTHLY    0    BASIS_POINTS
```

Now I want to select rows which have the max(Val) and min(Val) at one.
i.e I want to select the below two rows at once from the above table

```
Mand_ID Type            Sub_Type D_Freq Limit_Type      mon_freq   Val  Units
======= =======         ======== ====== ===========     =========  ===  ======  
IAC901  TRACKING_ERROR  EX_ANTE  NA     LESS_THAN       MONTHLY    450  BASIS_POINTS
IAC901  TRACKING_ERROR  EX_ANTE  NA     GREATER_THAN_EQ MONTHLY    0    BASIS_POINTS
```

Note: there are many different values for `Mand_ID` in the table; I want the rows with the largest and smallest values for each separate `Mand_ID`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. The standard response to a question like this is 'what have you tried?'  Providing that information helps us understand where you're coming from.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from theTable t, 
     (select max(val) as max_val, min(val) as min_val from theTable) as max_min
where t.val=max_min.max_val or t.val=max_min.min_val
```

Comment: Actually the above query will only return the rows with max and min value of val column.

But I want to select max and min of all such Mand_id . There are many such Mand_id in the table not just IAC901

Comment: Then add GROUP BY Mand_id in the subquery and max_min.Mand_id=t.Mand_id

Answer (score -1):

Let's suppose that the table is a text file loaded from main bundle:

```
TestText is:

Mand_ID Type            Sub_Type D_Freq Limit_Type      mon_freq   Val  Units
======= =======         ======== ====== ===========     =========  ==== ======= 
IAC901  TRACKING_ERROR  EX_ANTE  NA     LESS_THAN       MONTHLY    200  BASIS_POINTS
IAC901  TRACKING_ERROR  EX_ANTE  NA     GREATER_THAN    MONTHLY    150  BASIS_POINTS
IAC901  TRACKING_ERROR  EX_ANTE  NA     LESS_THAN       MONTHLY    450  BASIS_POINTS
IAC901  TRACKING_ERROR  EX_ANTE  NA     GREATER_THAN_EQ MONTHLY    0    BASIS_POINTS
```

than...

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestText"
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                       error: nil];


NSArray *array = [content componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

NSString *numberString;
int MinIndex=0,MaxIndex=0,MinVal=0,MaxVal = 0;
BOOL FirstTrackingError=YES;

for (int i=0;i<[array count];++i)
{
    if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:@"TRACKING_ERROR"].location != NSNotFound)
    {

        NSRange range = [[array objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:@"MONTHLY"];
        NSString *substring = [[array objectAtIndex:i] substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(range)];

        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: substring];
        NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

        // Throw away characters before the first number.
        [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet: numbers intoString:NULL];

        // Collect numbers.
        [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&numberString];


        if(FirstTrackingError == YES)
        {
            MinIndex=MaxIndex=i;
            MinVal=MaxVal=[numberString intValue];
            FirstTrackingError=NO;
        }
        else
        {
            if ([numberString intValue] > MaxVal)
            {
                MaxVal=[numberString intValue];
                MaxIndex=i;
            }
            else if ([numberString intValue] < MinVal)
            {
                MinVal=[numberString intValue];
                MinIndex=i;
            }
        }

    }

}


NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:MinIndex]);
NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:MaxIndex]);

NSString *result=[array objectAtIndex:MaxIndex];
result=[result stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n%@",[array objectAtIndex:MinIndex]];

NSLog(@"Result : \r\n%@",result);

The result is:

IAC901  TRACKING_ERROR  EX_ANTE  NA     LESS_THAN       MONTHLY    450  BASIS_POINTS
IAC901  TRACKING_ERROR  EX_ANTE  NA     GREATER_THAN_EQ MONTHLY    0    BASIS_POINTS
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  I think this is the first time I've seen an Objective-C program posted as the answer to an SQL question.  I'm sorry, but because it is Objective-C and is processing a text file rather than using ODBC or an equivalent, your answer is incorrect for the question, even if it produces the correct output based on the (faulty) assumptions you made.

Comment: Which faulty assumption, that we are talking about text file?

Comment: Well, I'm labouring under the illusion that the first few lines of code are referring to a resource (which I'd consider a file) rather than a Sybase DBMS as the question asks about.  I certainly don't see anything that looks like an SQL statement.  And I'm assuming that you assumed that the question was about processing a data file and not about writing an SQL statement -- whereas to my eye, this is a question about how to write an SQL statement to get a specific result set.